# Is there an algorithm to compute a single component of all eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $H$ be a Hermitian matrix, with eigenvectors $\{\mathbf{v}_{1},\dots,\mathbf{v}_{N}\}$. Suppose we want to calculate the overlap of each of these eigenvectors with the same vector $\mathbf{u}$, i.e. we want to calculate

$$ \mathbf{c} = \begin{pmatrix}|\langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}_{1} \rangle|^{2} \\ \vdots \\ | \langle \mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}_{N} \rangle |^{2}\end{pmatrix},$$

for the standard Euclidean inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$. Let us assume that $H$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_{1} > \lambda_{2} > \cdots > \lambda_{N}$ so that $\mathbf{c}$ is well defined.

**Question:** is there an algorithm that allows us to compute $\mathbf{c}$ *without* calculating the full eigensystem of $H$?

I wondered whether we could use some version of a Lanczos-based algorithm, if we could find a known matrix which has $\mathbf{c}$ as an eigenvector, but I can't immediately see how to do that. This intuition did make me hopeful that if such an algorithm did exist, the required computational effort could be comparable to that of computing a single eigenvector, but that might be wishful thinking!

Comment: The unit matrix is obviously a matrix that has $\boldsymbol{c}$ as eigenvector. Surely I am missing something here.

Comment: @Kurt, yes, of course. I was very vague with my suggestion, sorry! What I had in mind — though I have no idea if this is the right way to do it — was to find some matrix $M$, probably involving some function of $H$, which has $\mathbf{c}$ as an eigenvector, *and* with a corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$ which is separated from the rest of the spectrum of $M$. If you had an idea of the value of $\lambda$, then you could use a shift-invert algorithm to compute $\mathbf{c}$. This fails for $M = \mathrm{id}$ because all its eigenvalues are the same.

Comment: Even if all eigenvalues of $H$ are pairwise different and vector $u$ is fixed, it is still possible to obtain any vector from $\mathbb{R}^N$ with nonzero coordinates as vector $c$ with suitable choice of eigenvectors.

Comment: @kabenyuk That is true. But does that imply a negative answer to my question? I don't see why that would be the case if we have, say, access to the action of $H$ on vectors, which seems sufficient to resolve the ambiguity you describe.

Comment: The vector $c$ is not defined unless then eigenvalues are distinct. No such algorithm can therefore exists in general. We need additional assumptions to make progress on this interesting question. Please tell us more us more about the underlying problem.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for your comment — it would be fine for my purposes to assume that $H$ has distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: On second thought, even when the eigenvalues are distinct there are still issues. We would obviously normalize the eigenvectors to unit length, but if $v$ is an eigenvector of $H$ with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then so is $-v$. Flipping the direction of $v_j$ changes the sign of $c_j = v_j^Tu$.

Comment: Ah, that's also true. In fact I am only interested in the magnitude of the overlaps, which removes the issue. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to prove that something is impossible, but I see no reason to be optimistic in this case.

Firstly, your use of the bracket notation and word "overlap" suggest that you application is related to quantum mechanics. Here the vector $c$ expresses the probability of finding the system in one of the $n$ eigenstates. Now, if a simple algorithm existed, then it would almost certainly be known at this time. There are simply too many people who would benefit too much from such an algorithm. Now, this is true for any field right up to the point where somebody makes a breakthrough, so don't give up because of this argument.

However, your problem is only slightly easier than computing $d = V^T u$ for an arbitrary vector $u$ without explicit access to a matrix $V$ consisting of the eigenvectors of $H$. This problem is clearly more general/difficult than that of computing a single eigenvector. [This case corresponds to $u$ being a column of the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix.] Now we can get typically a single eigenvector using inverse iteration (a generalization of the power method). In general, this requires $O(n^3)$ operations unless $H$ is already tridiagonal in which case the cost is only $O(n^2)$ operations.

Again this does not prove anything, but my intuition is that what you seek sadly does not exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed my interest is in quantum mechanics, and such an algorithm would be very valuable in that context — but I agree with your intuition that this problem is likely to be hard in general.

Comment: @anon1802 You are very welcome. If you solve the problem or formally prove that it cannot be done, then your proof would deserve to be published.